# PHP Login & Remember Me

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

Evening all,

I'm having a nightmare with cookies. I've tried a million and one ways to keep users logged in but fail.

My login.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); exit(); }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!isset($_POST['username'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";
    if (!isset($_POST['password'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if ( $user->isValidUsername($username)){
        if (!isset($_POST['password'])){
            $error[] = 'A password must be entered';
        }
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if($user->login($username,$password)){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
        }
    }else{
        $error[] = 'Usernames are required to be Alphanumeric, and between 3-16 characters long';
    }
}
?>
```

and on the pages that need the user to be logged currently using at the top of the page.

```
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: profile.php'); exit(); }
```

Any advice for how I can add cookies to my existing script? I'm not highly skilled in PHP so looking for something basic but secure. Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried calling `session_start()` so that sessions actually happen?

Comment: why the cookies tag? I only see sessions here.

Comment: start by enabling error reporting and this seems db-related, so check for errors on the query also.

Comment: @Sammitch I have that in my global config.php

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I've tried multiple ways but can't get any to work. Was looking for suggestions or advice given my codebase?

Comment: Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Tried debugging, nothing relevant.

Comment: `I'm having a nightmare with cookie` and yet nothing with `$_COOKIE` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php  **Remember Me** will require a cookie other then that of the Session.  Session lifetimes are short (that's the point) and you need a longer lived cookie for remembering a user, and several security considerations.  Beyond that there is not enough context to really tell what is wrong.